# Tofu as a growing medium?

Tags: growth, growing-medium, legumes

I just had a strange idea of no actual significance, but I was just staring at a block of tofu and wondered if you could plant things in it. Has anyone tried this? How does/would tofu fair as a growing medium. How would plants grow differently in hard, medium, and soft tofu?

Comment: Where should the oxygen come from?

Comment: To me, it seems to strong and dense, to be able to absorb nutrients to give back to roots. I have also no idea on how it will rot.

Comment: Molds like it. Maybe *dictyostelium discoideum* https://www.google.com/search?q=dictostellium+discodium&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1 You've little to lose by trying.

Answer (score 1):

As I have made tofu itself I would not do this.

Tofu is made from soaking soybeans and then grinding them into a fine slurry, cooking it for a while to extract any oils/proteins and then straining it through something fine to remove the bits of bean left over.  At this point you have soymilk.

To make Tofu then it is curdled with various substances (vinegar, lemon juice, etc.) similar to how a cheese is made and then the curds are pressed to get rid of the extra liquid.

This resulting mass is the tofu which you'd be planting into.  So now the question becomes which plants would grow in a block of acidic coagulated proteins and fats?  I don't know of any that may do great with this, but perhaps after drying it out a bit you could coat it with some moss spores and then other plants would gradually colonize it and break it down.